# Getting OverMaxRecordSize while fetching single record from AWS S3 Select?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

I am getting an error **OverMaxRecordSize: The character number in one record is more than our max threshold, maxCharsPerRecord: 1,048,576** when I'm trying to fetch any particular record from AWS S3 using **selectObjectContent** function.

If I'm fetching 10 records its working but if trying to fetch one of them then it's throwing above error.

As I can see the reason for the error in AWS documentation is "The length of a record in the input or result is greater than maxCharsPerRecord of 1 MB."

Please suggest any solution or workaround as my data is location data and its size can be more than 1 MB.

For example:

**Working**: select * from s3object s limit 10;

**Not Working**: select * from s3object s where id = '22'

My parameters are:

```
const params = {
      Key: 'locationdata2020.csv.gz',
      ExpressionType: 'SQL',
      Expression: `select * from s3object  s where id = '22';`,
      InputSerialization: {
        CSV: {
          FileHeaderInfo: 'USE',
          RecordDelimiter: '\n',
          FieldDelimiter: ','
        },
        CompressionType: 'GZIP'
      },
      OutputSerialization: {
        JSON: {
          RecordDelimiter: ','
        }

      }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is a limitation of the AWS solution. We had a similar issue and ended up batch processing the data first and storing some aggregations to another bucket which we then queried using `SelectObjectContent`.